# So I can't mock a method that is implemented in C

Tags: ruby

Look at https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/1408b942d9c2c131a1cdcab97f49d74ce84dae38

I thought mocking meant you can mock any method. Did not know that methods that are implemented in C can't be mocked. Why?

I guess that means I don't really understand how mocking works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with mocking methods in C and is only about method dependecy.

If you read attentively, the commit states that mocking `Time.now` no longer has an impact on `Date.today`.

In Ruby 1.8.7, `Date.today` was implemented in Ruby and was calling `Time.now`. In newer Ruby, `Date.today` is in C and does not call `Time.now`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's up with that, because Double Ruby https://github.com/btakita/rr seems capable of doing it:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'test/unit'
require 'rr'

extend RR::Adapters::RRMethods

class MockTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  include RR::Adapters::TestUnit

  def test_can_mock_c_method
    a = [1,5,3]
    mock(a).sort{'foo!'}
    assert_equal 'foo!', a.sort
  end

end
```

This is using MRI 1.8.7, and as far as I can tell, Enumerable#sort and Array#sort are implemented in C.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.